# how to refactor .bind(this) into ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

for example I have this React component which simply does loading text. I have a problem with refactoring .bind(this) to es6 syntax.

```
var Loading = React.createClass({

getInitialState:() => {
this.originalText = 'Loading';
   return {
       text: 'Loading'
   }
},

componentDidMount:function() {
   let stopper = this.originalText + '...' ;
   this.interval = setInterval(function(){
       if(this.state.text === stopper) {
           this.setState({
               text:this.originalText
           })
       }else {
           this.setState({
               text: this.state.text + '.'
           })
       }
   }.bind(this), 300)
},


render: function () {
   return (
       <div style={styles.container}>
           <p style={styles.content}>{this.state.text}</p>
       </div>
   )
  }
});
```

here I want to refactor

```
}.bind(this), 300)
```

to ES6 syntax. What would be solution.

Comment: Looks like somebody threw up with downvotes all over the question.

Comment: And all the answers... not cool because those were legitimate answers to the question

Comment: yep :( rage serial downvoter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace:

```
this.interval = setInterval(function(){
    /* ... */
}.bind(this), 300)
```

with:

```
 this.interval = setInterval( () => {
    /* ... */
 }, 300)
```

That's because arrow functions automatically binds. BTW, I refactored all your component code to ES6:

```
class Loading extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.originalText = 'Loading'
    this.state = {
      text: 'Loading'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let stopper = this.originalText + '...' ;
    this.interval = setInterval( () => {
      if(this.state.text === stopper) {
        this.setState({
          text:this.originalText
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          text: this.state.text + '.'
        })
      }
    }, 300)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        <p style={styles.content}>{this.state.text}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/jgtyetwu/

Answer (score 1):

Still `}.bind(this), 300)`. ES6 is backwards compatible.

You could also use an arrow function (as you do to define `getInitialState`).

Answer (score 1):

`function () { ... }.bind(this)` is what arrow function is supposed to do.

It is

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => { ... }, 300)
```